# modestbranding parameter for YouTube JS API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm generating a chromeless YouTube player on my webpage using YouTube's JavaScript API.
I was hoping to somehow remove the YouTube logo in the bottom right hand corner of the player using the 'modestbranding' parameter I'm aware of, but I've only been able to find it in documents relating to the iFrame API.

Is it possible to use this parameter somehow in the JavaScript API?

Comment: Nop. If you use Chromeless you can't use modestbranding. The Youtube logo will always be visible in the video. It's a logical limitation.

Comment: @elclanrs - what if i was to use the JS API for an embedded player, instead of the JS API for a chromeless player?